# I want to calculate $\int B(t)^2 dB(t)$ where $B(t)$ is Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let $B(t)$ be Brownian motion. I want to calculate $\int B(t)^2 dB(t)$.

definition.A process $\{X(t),0\le t \le T \}$ is called a simple adapted
process if there exist times $0=t_{0}<t_{1}<t_{2}<\cdots<t_{n}=T $ and random variables $\eta_{0},\eta_{1},\cdots,\eta_{n}$ such that $\eta_{0}$ is a constant,$\eta_{i}$ is $\mathcal F_{i}$-measurable,For simple adapted processes Ito integral $\int X dB$ is defined as a sum $$\int_{0}^{T}X(t)dB(t)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\eta_{i}(B(t_{i+1}-B(t_{i}))$$

thanks for help

Comment: Your question produced a little bit more discussion on http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78025/i-want-to-calculate-int-bt2-dbt-where-bt-is-brownian-motion, you could try to answer the questions people asked there, rather than just repost your question here. How do you solve $\int B(T)dB(t)$? What is $T$? What are the limits of your integral?

Comment: @UwF.i edit my qiestion

Comment: @saz.i edit my qiestion

Comment: @pualambagher : if you post the same question on two different Stack Exchange sites, you should include this information in both questions, with links.

Comment: @pualambagher Do you know Itô's formula? (Actually, the integral $\int_0^T B_t^2 \,dB_t$ can be calculated explicitely using approximation of the integrand by simple processes, but this involves much more calculations.)

Comment: What is meant by "to compute a random variable"? (Again crossposted with no mention of the fact? These are bad manners.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Itô's formula indicates that for every nonnegative deterministic $t$,
$$
\int_0^tB_s^2\mathrm dB_s=\tfrac13B_t^3-\int_0^tB_s\mathrm ds=\tfrac13B_t^3-tB_t+\int_0^ts\mathrm dB_s.
$$
To determine whether this "computes" the random variable on the LHS or not, one would need to know what it means to "compute a random variable" (the notion escapes me).

Comment: if it possible for you i want the Process.give me a link or Introduce a book. thank you.

Comment: Apply Itô to $(B_t)^3$.